# Is it possible to place a picture on a TOC that appears before each section?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I want to show my TOC before each section. However, I am hiding my subsections, which makes the slide look bare. Is it possible to add in a image on the right side (away from the text)? I have provided my code below...I forgot to mention I'm using beamer, which is obviously important.

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{Dresden}
    \usepackage{multirow, makecell}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{mwe}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Outline}
        \begin{columns}[t]
            \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
                \footnotesize
                \tableofcontents[sections={1-2}]
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
                \footnotesize
                \tableofcontents[sections={3-4}]
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}

    \section{Introduction}
    \frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection,hideallsubsections,subsubsectionstyle=hide]}

    \subsection{Stream Bioenergetics}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Stream Bioenergetics}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Energy availability (upstream to downstream movement)
    \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a compilable document, not just fragments

Comment: Sorry, just did that now Christian

Comment: Why not just use \includegraphics on every page you want the table of contents?  If you want it on the right, you've already got the columns set up for it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the same technique as on your first toc:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \footnotesize
            \tableofcontents[sections={1-2}]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \footnotesize
            \tableofcontents[sections={3-4}]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}[T]
      \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
          \footnotesize
          \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideallsubsections,subsubsectionstyle=hide]
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
      \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Stream Bioenergetics}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Stream Bioenergetics}
\begin{itemize}
\item Energy availability (upstream to downstream movement)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]